# Not sure how user defined type records/elements are populated

Tags: vb6, user-defined-types

In this code I don't understand how the records *IngLower* and *IngUpper* of the LargeInt type are populated. For instance, if I add *udtFreeBytesAvail*  to the watch list and set a breakpoint at the 16th line the records of *udtFreeBytesAvail* become populated, I know it's because of the parameters of the API function *GetDiskFreeSpaceEx*, but I don't understand why both records become populated, and not just one for example. And also why both records have different values. I appreciate your help, and sorry if my problem is not well described as I'm new to programming.

```
Public Type LargeInt
   lngLower As Long
   lngUpper As Long
End Type

Public Declare Function GetDiskFreeSpaceEx Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "GetDiskFreeSpaceExA" (ByVal   lpDirectoryName As String, lpFreeBytesAvailableToCaller As LargeInt, lpTotalNumberOfBytes As LargeInt, lpTotalNumberofFreeBytes As LargeInt) As Long

Public Function FreeDiskSpace(ByVal sDriveLetter As String) As Double

Dim udtFreeBytesAvail As LargeInt, udtTtlBytes As LargeInt
Dim udtTTlFree As LargeInt
Dim dblFreeSpace As Double

    If GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(sDriveLetter, udtFreeBytesAvail, udtTtlBytes, udtTTlFree) Then

            If udtFreeBytesAvail.lngLower < 0 Then
               dblFreeSpace = udtFreeBytesAvail.lngUpper * 2 ^ 32 + udtFreeBytesAvail.lngLower + 4294967296#
            Else
               dblFreeSpace = udtFreeBytesAvail.lngUpper * 2 ^ 32 + udtFreeBytesAvail.lngLower
            End If

    End If

FreeDiskSpace = dblFreeSpace

End Function
```

Comment: It would help if you started out by learning what language you are using and also how to use online resources. That is not VB.NET code and the descriptions for the VBA and VB.NET tags explicitly state that they are not to be used for the questions on the other.

Comment: `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` populates it

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're referring to as a "record", mind clarifying? What are the "both records" with "different values" mentioned? What are these values? Also since you're new at programming, now is the perfect time to [unlearn Hungarian Notation](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/).

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm using Visual Basic 6.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I have read it in a book, the elements of a user-defined type can be seen as records. Thanks.

Comment: My understanding has been that a variable pointing to a UDT (/declared `As` one) is a "record" - the term is also used in the database world, referring to a "row" in a table: a variable pointing to a UDT is able to hold a whole such record. Best stick to simple terms to be clearly understood by all: UDT is the data type, and a UDT field (note database-like terminology again) or UDT member is an "element" of a UDT aka "record"

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: *"I'm using Visual Basic 6"*. So use the VB6 tag then, not two tags that both tell you not to use them for VB6 in their description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other already explained it, but as you still seem to struggle to understand *why* it works, let me try and clarify this:

The UDT "keeps" its members (the 2 Long integers in this case) in a *consecutive* memory location, the 1st byte of lngUpper directly follows the last byte of lngLower, occupying in total 8 bytes (=64 bits) *consecutive* memory. The API GetDiskFreeSpaceEx writes 64 *consecutive* bits at the start of the variables provided to it as lpFreeBytesAvailableToCaller etc. Hence it "fills out" both 32 bit Long variables of the UDT.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a parameter by reference (`ByRef` - note that it's the [implicit default](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitByRefModifier)) and then assign it in that procedure...

```
Public Sub DoThing(ByRef value As Long)
    value = 42
End Sub
```

Then to invoke that procedure you need to give it an argument - if you just give it a literal...

```
DoThing 10
```

...then nothing happens, the variable pointer just falls out of scope. But give it a local variable...

```
Dim local As Long
DoThing local

Debug.Print local
```

And that should output `42`.

This is exactly what's going on here, except instead of a local variable, it's a UDT member - T.S. put it succinctly:

> `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` populates it – [T.S. 8 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60647521/not-sure-how-user-defined-type-records-elements-are-populated#comment107298300_60647521)

---

```
Public Declare Function GetDiskFreeSpaceEx Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "GetDiskFreeSpaceExA" ( _
    ByVal lpDirectoryName As String, _
    lpFreeBytesAvailableToCaller As LargeInt, _
    lpTotalNumberOfBytes As LargeInt, _
    lpTotalNumberofFreeBytes As LargeInt) As Long
```

The function itself returns a `Long` integer, but the *real* output is the `ByRef` parameters it takes - notice the *inputs* are passed by value (`ByVal`).

---

> *I don't understand why both records become populated, and not just one for example*

Assuming "records" is about the UDT members `lngLower` and `lngUpper`, it's really just what a UDT does... You need to play with them a little, see how they work. Try making your own procedure that takes a UDT:

```
Public Sub DoThing(ByRef value As LargeInt)
    value.lngLower = 1
    value.lngUpper = 2
End Sub
```

The API function is doing pretty much exactly that - there are two values because a `LargeInt` **is** two values.

Comment: Although this doesn't answer my question, it's very helpful nonetheless. Thanks.

Comment: This absolutely does answer your question, btw. Particularly the closing statement.

Comment: I looked up Large Integer in the API Viewer and found an API Type called _Large_Integer_, the API type has two elements _lowpart_ and _highpart_. What's the use of this API Type? Thank you.

Comment: @VoidLT my first thought for replying was "where to begin" - I'd suggest you learn to walk before you try running. As suggested above, you need to play with UDTs and see how they work. No amount of reading can substitute for that hands-on experience. Once you understand what UDTs are, how they work, and how it doesn't matter what specific UDT type you're using as long as the field layout is the same (cross-process -- VBA will enforce type safety here), you'll find that, as is the case for any struct type, its use is to carry data between procedures - same as any other parameter.

Comment: @VoidLT basically the API you want to consume involves a struct layout that involves two 32-bit integer values; one to hold the "upper" bits, the other to hold the "lower" bits. The result is a data type that can hold a 64-bit integer value, i.e. a "large integer". So you define a struct with that same layout - in VBA that's done with a UDT type - and then you can consume that API in VBA.

Comment: In 64-bit VBA7 you would use a `LongLong` to hold a 64-bit integer value, but 32-bit VBA needs to cheat in order to be able to store a 64-bit integer with one variable pointer - that `LargeInteger` struct is how.

Comment: I guess I need a lot of walking. Thank you for your answer.